# Trying to set up Python to work on my company provided windows laptop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am an absolute beginner to Python and the world of programming languages. As of right now in my role, I'll be using it specifically to scape contents to build emails.

My struggle is that I don't know how to map to the contents (like files, etc.) on my system to be scraped using Python.

Not sure if this will make any sense, but it's been happening to me since I installed Python. Every time I type in "cd", "dir", or "ls", it keeps bringing up a message that says:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'x' is not defined."

What am I supposed to do if and when this occurs?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use the Python interpreter as if it's a version of `bash`: it's not.

Comment: When you are in the Python interpretter, you can only use Python syntax.  Operations that are part of the shell (bash, zsh, crosh, etc) are not part of the Python language.

Answer (score -1):

In terms of using your Python code to interact with the files on your system, you are going to need to import the OS module into your code. Here is a small code snip that will do that for you and print the current working directory:

```
# Python program to explain os.getcwd() method
        
# importing os module
import os
    
# Get the current working
# directory (CWD)
cwd = os.getcwd()
    
# Print the current working
# directory (CWD)
print("Current working directory:", cwd)
```

This code was sourced from [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/os-module-python-examples/) and if you follow it, it has more good information about using the OS module in Python to interact with the files on your system. Another good resource for learning Python automation is the free online ebook [Automate The Boring Stuff With Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/).

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of working with the os package. The OP sounds more like he is using IDLE as CLI